# How to instruct Json method how to serialize a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

In .net, I'm currently doing this:

```
public JsonResult GetStuff() {

  return Json(myClassInstance.Result); // Result => { data: something, message: something } 
}
```

I feel quite annoyed by having to specify Result every time I call Json on a`MyClass` instance. Is there a way to instruct Json how to look for property to get data for serialization ? Or a template method to call for serialization ?

```
// Something like this, when Json detect there is this method on the object class, it will invoke this method.
// ....


// Inside MyClass
public string ToJSON() {
  // serialize property

}
```

Comment: Would love to know what's wrong with the question for downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make an extension method for the `Controller` class. Something like this:

```
    public static JsonResult ToMyJson(this Controller controller, MyType myData)
    {
        return controller.Json(myData.Result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this at the moment:

```
public class MyData
{
    public MyResult Result { get; set; }
}

public MyData GetData() { return new MyData(); }

MyData data = GetData();
return Json(data.Result);
```

Then, you basically have two options:

1.You can remove the usage of MyData:

```
public MyResult GetData() { return new MyData().Result; }

MyResult data = GetData();
return Json(data);
```

2.Or you could use a helper method (either as a BaseController or extension) (as @TeodorKurtev wrote)